# NAnt newbie - support chart

Tags: runtime, nant, target

Will any of you guys be kind and explain the **framework support chart** shown here: [nant.sourceforge.net](http://nant.sourceforge.net/).

My primary interest is the meaning of the terms **target** and **runtime** in the context of nant?

Thanks in advance / derdres

Answer (score 1):

**Target** refers to the supported frameworks against which you can compile your projects (i.e., with NAnt, you can compile .NET 3.5 projects, Mono 2.0 projects, Silverlight 2.0 projects, etc.).

**Runtime** refers to the frameworks on which NAnt can be run (for instance, if you have .NET 1.0 installed, you can run NAnt).